# location for pic in exams Rnw file

Tags: r, markdown, r-exams

I am trying to add a picture with \includegraphics{pic.png} into a question of an .Rnw file from the [exams package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exams/index.html).

Something along the lines of:

```
\begin{question}
What day is today: \includegraphics{picture.png}

\begin{answerlist}
  \item \Sexpr{questions[1]}
  \item \Sexpr{questions[2]}
  \item \Sexpr{questions[3]}
  \item \Sexpr{questions[4]}
\end{answerlist}

\end{question}
```

running exams2pdf then

```
exams2pdf(myexam, n = 1, nsamp = 2, dir = odir, 
                   template = c("my_exam", "solution"), 
                   encoding = 'UTF-8',
                   header = list(
                     Date = "30.05.2017"))
```

gives me:

```
Error in texi2dvi(out_tex[j], pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE, quiet = quiet) : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'my_exam1.tex' failed.
LaTeX errors:
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `picture.png' not found.
```

I tried pretty much all the directories the pic could be in but tex2dvi / exams2pdf does not find the png - any advice on that?

Comment: What is your question? Do you have an error? What did you try?

Comment: now with the full question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exams output files (PDF in this case) are compiled in a different directory than the current working directory. Hence, any supplementary files need to be flagged as such so that they are copied around as needed. The package provides the `include_supplement()` function for this purpose and `exams2pdf("Rlogo")` contains a worked example. In your case the exercise Rnw should be:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
include_supplement("picture.png")
@

\begin{question}
What does the following logo stand for?

...
\end{question}
```

If needed, also specify `include_supplement("picture.png", dir = "/path/to/files/")`.

Two further hints: (1) The answerlist could also be generated as

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
answerlist(questions)
@
```

This is a feature that we have added a few years after many of the documentation/examples which is why it is not visible so prominently. (2) If you have only single-choice or multiple-choice questions the `exams2nops()` function might also be of interest to you. This is a PDF output format that can be automatically scanned and evaluated within R.

If you need further advice you can either ask here (with `exams` tag) or in our support forum on R-Forge at https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=4377

Comment: Can you help me find documentation on what the `<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=` header does?  It's hard to pattern-match these templates without more context.

Comment: This is standard `Sweave` syntax for an R code chunk whose input should not be shown in the resulting document (`echo=FALSE`) and whose output is suppressed as well (`results=hide`). In other word, the entire code chunk is hidden in the resulting document. Google for `Sweave` tutorials for more information. Also, if you're RStudio this provides nice interactive tool tips when editing Rnw files.